# insert data in a field on the basis of condition, in MySql (PhpMyadmin)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I have: Crew table with every field full of data except one single field, that is, Crew_status... it represents the availability of any crew, that whether he/she is available for next flight or not.

My problem: i want to insert "unavailable" in the crew_status of that specific crew who has been allocated to some flight. To do this, i will have to use where clause inorder to figure out whether flight_name is empty or has some data. if it is empty(which means crew has not been allocated yet), I want to insert `available` in its `crew_status` field.. and if it is not empty(which means crew has been allocated to any flight), I want to insert `unavailable` in its crew_status field....
.
how can i do that ? I am having error

> syntax error near: "='unavailable' where flight_name='fl243'"

My Module is:

```
public void availability(string table_name, string field_name, string where_clause1, string where_clause2, string status)
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update " + table_name + "set "+field_name+"='" + status + "' where " + where_clause1+"='"+where_clause2+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            con.Close();         }
```

NOTE: `table_name="crew"`  ,  `field_name="crew_status"` `Whereclause1="flight_name"` , `Whereclause2="fl243"`  ,  `status="unavailable"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a space between `table_name` and  `set`

```
"update " + table_name + " set "+field_name+"='" + status + "' where " + where_clause1+"='"+where_clause2+"'";
```